# Help me connecting java and oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Can anybody explain me these classes and methods?

```
DriverManager.registerDriver
(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdb:ocracle:thin:username/password@machine.us.company.com:1234:dbSID");
```

Thanks

Comment: You have a couple typos in your JDBC URL. Should start like "jdbc:oracle:"

Answer (score 4):

Let's decode the lines of your code block:

```
1. DriverManager.registerDriver
2. (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
3. conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
4. "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@machine.us.company.com:1234:dbSID");
```

Line 2:

Creates a new instance of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`, a JDBC `Driver` for the Oracle database. A JDBC driver implements the interfaces and classes defined by the JDBC API that programmers use to connect to a database and perform queries.

Line 1

Registers the instance of the `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` to the [`DriverManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) class which is the traditional management layer of JDBC, working between the user and the drivers. It handles establishing a connection between a database and the appropriate driver.

Line 3:

Now that the communication layer between the JDBC application and the database is ready, you can create a connection by calling [`getConnection()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String%29) method of the [`DriverManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) class.

Line 4:

This is the "connection string" or "database URL". This `String` identifies the database you want to connect to. The scheme of this URL is specific to the database provider and/or the driver (here, Oracle and its "thin" driver).

---

Note that prior to Java 6, calling `Class.forName` was the preferred way to load and register a JDBC Driver. It was the responsibility of the `Driver` to call [`DriverManager.registerDriver`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver%28java.sql.Driver%29).

> [...] All `Driver` classes should be written with a static section (a static initializer) that creates an instance of the class and then registers it with the `DriverManager` class when it is loaded. Thus, a user would not normally call `DriverManager.registerDriver` directly; it should be called automatically by a `Driver` class when it is loaded.

Check the [Driver Manager](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/drivermanager.html) chapter from the JDBC documentation for more details.

Comment: thanx 4 ur answer
i realy appreciate that
good luck
RAQ Report
www.raqsoft.com

Comment: You should know that the oracle.jdbc.driver package is de-supported for customer use by Oracle. From now on the oracle.jdbc package should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The `DriverManager` class in java handles the connections between the database and the jdbc drivers, routing db i/o to the correct jdbc driver (you can have multiple drivers active ie connections to multiple types of database).

Drivers are registered with the DriverManager so that they become part of its working set. The next step is to create a connection to your database, so you can run queries. This is achived by the

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdb:ocracle:thin:username/password@machine.us.company.com:1234:dbSID")
```

method. The connection String passed into the `getConnection()` method is driver-specific, you need to RTFM for each driver. Note that the `DriverManager` selects the driver automatically from its list of registered drivers, according to the syntax of the connection string you pass in.

The Connection object returned is your handle for preparing statements and running queries against the database

Comment: According to the javadoc: Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using <code>Class.forName()</code>. Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using <code>Class.forName()</code> will continue to work without modification.

Comment: Please forgive the poor bastards stuck in 1.4.2 because of compatibility constraints

Comment: Good thinking, problem gone (I hope)

Answer (score 0):

This is JDBC which is the way Java programs talk to a database, and  your sample explicitly asks for the Oracle driver which requires their driver in your classpath.

Sun has a good tutorial on the matter at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html